# Balancing between performance, convenience & separation

Tags: web-applications, performance, server-side, client-side

Consider a web application that works with somewhat sensitive data on reliable, high performance clients.

The data needs to be processed and manipulated. So far I have learned that when possible, data processing should be a serverside concern because of the following reasons (amongst others)

- There is no data exposed that shouldn't be
- You can't rely on client performance

Nevertheless, I would like to to processing clientside because of the following reasons:

- There are a lot of operations that need to be done on the same set of data. If i would do them serverside, I would have to do a lot of requests which will cause ugly & bloated client side code. If I do things on the client, I can use a convenient service which exposes a neat API. This is the main reason for me.
- If I load the data on initialization, I don't have to rely on the server further.
- The application is used in-house only. I know the clients and don't have to burden the server with operations I know the client is perfectly capable of doing.

---

So, when can I do data operations client side with good conscience?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

If the your data operations are about a set of data specific for a client, they should be done on the client.

They are not "data operations" as usually meant. Work on data obtained belong not to `data server`, but to `application server`. And the last can easily be done more thin making clients a bit thicker. It is not against some common rules. Finding the correct balance is wholely on you.